# Margins from the column separator

Tags: spacing, margins, two-column

If the text in both columns end and begin too close from the column separator, how do I increase the margin from it?

Change from:

```
| #Text#######|#Text####### | % (Bad, too close to column separator)
| ############|############ |
| ############|###########  |
| ####        |  ########## |
| ############|############ |
| ############|############ |
| ############|############ |
| ############|############ |
| ########    |#########    |
```

to:

```
| #Text####### | #Text####### | % (Much better)
| ############ | ############ |
| ############ | ###########  |
| ####         |   ########## |
| ############ | ############ |
| ############ | ############ |
| ############ | ############ |
| ############ | ############ |
| ########     | #########    |
```

Comment: Do you use the `multicol` package or LaTeX in-built mechanism?

Comment: using `multicol`

Comment: Did you set the `columnsep` parameter?

Comment: No, I didn't. I'm using default values.

Comment: Next time, you should read the documentation first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using

```
 \setlength{\columnsep}{2cm}
```

or whatever value suits you.